# Why am I getting the error no match for operator= in 'a = x'?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to understand the new C++ 11 features; more specifically, the reference qualifiers (one of which) restricts the assignment onto rvalues. But for some reason I can't get this code to work. The errors I get arise when I assign the `A` object `a` to the lvalue `x` ( `a = x` ).

> prog.cpp:5:47: error: expected initializer before `'&'` token
>   prog.cpp: In function `'int main()'`:
>   prog.cpp:15:9: error: no match for `'operator='` in `'a = x'`
>   prog.cpp:3:10: note: candidate is: `A& A::operator=(const A&)`

```
struct A {

   template <typename T> auto operator = (T) & -> A & {
       return *this;
   }

};

int main() {

   A a;

   int x = 4;

   a = x;

}
```

The code works when I take the reference qualifier out. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems you're using GCC. Ref-qualifiers are currently only supported by Clang 3.1+. Your code compiles perfectly fine with that.

Comment: I *am* in fact using gcc. Thanks for the response.